# Stream desktop using VLC

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player, screencasts

I've been looking for a simple Desktop streaming solution via VLC. The only post of concern I could find was http://ifoundthesolution.blogspot.com/2008/02/screencasting-using-vlc.html, which is pretty old, and uses UDP.

I wanted to stream a single screen:// to 9 computers connected on the network. I've been able to do this for normal files, but I'm yet to find a transcoding setting that works for screen:// as well.

GUI solutions are preferred.

Comment: Do you want to know how to stream your screen to 9 screens with vlc or do you already know it and you just want to know fast/good transcoding settings? Changing your example to http works for me (change the IP to your source IP and change the port according to your needs): vlc.exe screen:// :screen-fps=30 :screen-caching=100 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=4096,acodec=mpga,ab=256,scale=1,width=1280,height=800}:standard{access=http, mux=ts, dst=192.168.0.1:8080}'

Comment: Didn't knew such a small change would work. Could you post your solution as an answer so I could mark it as correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 vlc.exe screen:// :screen-fps=30 :screen-caching=100 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=4096,acodec=mpga,ab=256,scale=1,width=1280,height=800‌​}:standard{access=http, mux=ts, dst=192.168.0.1:8080}'
```

Comment: this is amazing